# List.insert() inserting on wrong index

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I was writing a program where I would generate different numbers and organize them into different lists inside a dictionary. Here's the code:

```
import random

Key = {}

for NumberOfTimesRanThroughTheMainLoop in range(0, 5): #Runs x times
    print("Number of times ran through main loop (EF): " + str(NumberOfTimesRanThroughTheMainLoop + 1) + "/" + str(5))
    for SeparatedContent in " Hohoho ": #SeparatedContent = the content i gave the def
        rn = random.randint(0, 3000-1) # Random number from 1 to 2999
        print("Number generated: " + str(rn))
        if SeparatedContent in Key: #I can't use insert if the list doesn't exist, so it verifies whether it exists and if it doesn't, create it
            #NumberOfTimesRanThroughTheMainLoop is correct
            print("This is _i: " + str(NumberOfTimesRanThroughTheMainLoop))
            Key[SeparatedContent].insert(NumberOfTimesRanThroughTheMainLoop, rn)
        else:
            Key[SeparatedContent] = [ ]
            Key[SeparatedContent].insert(NumberOfTimesRanThroughTheMainLoop, rn)
        print("Length of list of the key that's being generated (Comparison with what it should): " + str(len(Key[SeparatedContent])) + " = " + str(5) )
print("Generated key = " + str(Key))
```

Here's the output

```
Number of times ran through main loop (EF): 1/5
Number generated: 1814
Length of list of the key that's being generated (Comparison with what it should): 1 = 5
Number generated: 281
Length of list of the key that's being generated (Comparison with what it should): 1 = 5
Number generated: 1011
Length of list of the key that's being generated (Comparison with what it should): 1 = 5
Number generated: 2641
Length of list of the key that's being generated (Comparison with what it should): 1 = 5
Number generated: 2532
This is _i: 0
Length of list of the key that's being generated (Comparison with what it should): 2 = 5
Number generated: 695
This is _i: 0
Length of list of the key that's being generated (Comparison with what it should): 2 = 5
Number generated: 2497
This is _i: 0
Length of list of the key that's being generated (Comparison with what it should): 3 = 5
Number generated: 955
This is _i: 0
Length of list of the key that's being generated (Comparison with what it should): 2 = 5
Number of times ran through main loop (EF): 2/5
Number generated: 1042
This is _i: 1
Length of list of the key that's being generated (Comparison with what it should): 3 = 5
Number generated: 1542
This is _i: 1
Length of list of the key that's being generated (Comparison with what it should): 2 = 5
Number generated: 720
This is _i: 1
Length of list of the key that's being generated (Comparison with what it should): 4 = 5
Number generated: 1168
This is _i: 1
Length of list of the key that's being generated (Comparison with what it should): 3 = 5
Number generated: 2367
This is _i: 1
Length of list of the key that's being generated (Comparison with what it should): 5 = 5
Number generated: 1207
This is _i: 1
Length of list of the key that's being generated (Comparison with what it should): 4 = 5
Number generated: 1384
This is _i: 1
Length of list of the key that's being generated (Comparison with what it should): 6 = 5
Number generated: 2811
This is _i: 1
Length of list of the key that's being generated (Comparison with what it should): 4 = 5
Number of times ran through main loop (EF): 3/5
Number generated: 1830
This is _i: 2
Length of list of the key that's being generated (Comparison with what it should): 5 = 5
Number generated: 2710
This is _i: 2
Length of list of the key that's being generated (Comparison with what it should): 3 = 5
Number generated: 339
This is _i: 2
Length of list of the key that's being generated (Comparison with what it should): 7 = 5
Number generated: 775
This is _i: 2
Length of list of the key that's being generated (Comparison with what it should): 5 = 5
Number generated: 1728
This is _i: 2
Length of list of the key that's being generated (Comparison with what it should): 8 = 5
Number generated: 2011
This is _i: 2
Length of list of the key that's being generated (Comparison with what it should): 6 = 5
Number generated: 88
This is _i: 2
Length of list of the key that's being generated (Comparison with what it should): 9 = 5
Number generated: 442
This is _i: 2
Length of list of the key that's being generated (Comparison with what it should): 6 = 5
Number of times ran through main loop (EF): 4/5
Number generated: 350
This is _i: 3
Length of list of the key that's being generated (Comparison with what it should): 7 = 5
Number generated: 516
This is _i: 3
Length of list of the key that's being generated (Comparison with what it should): 4 = 5
Number generated: 1885
This is _i: 3
Length of list of the key that's being generated (Comparison with what it should): 10 = 5
Number generated: 2176
This is _i: 3
Length of list of the key that's being generated (Comparison with what it should): 7 = 5
Number generated: 1242
This is _i: 3
Length of list of the key that's being generated (Comparison with what it should): 11 = 5
Number generated: 1369
This is _i: 3
Length of list of the key that's being generated (Comparison with what it should): 8 = 5
Number generated: 1332
This is _i: 3
Length of list of the key that's being generated (Comparison with what it should): 12 = 5
Number generated: 705
This is _i: 3
Length of list of the key that's being generated (Comparison with what it should): 8 = 5
Number of times ran through main loop (EF): 5/5
Number generated: 1091
This is _i: 4
Length of list of the key that's being generated (Comparison with what it should): 9 = 5
Number generated: 34
This is _i: 4
Length of list of the key that's being generated (Comparison with what it should): 5 = 5
Number generated: 1325
This is _i: 4
Length of list of the key that's being generated (Comparison with what it should): 13 = 5
Number generated: 377
This is _i: 4
Length of list of the key that's being generated (Comparison with what it should): 9 = 5
Number generated: 1861
This is _i: 4
Length of list of the key that's being generated (Comparison with what it should): 14 = 5
Number generated: 1593
This is _i: 4
Length of list of the key that's being generated (Comparison with what it should): 10 = 5
Number generated: 1758
This is _i: 4
Length of list of the key that's being generated (Comparison with what it should): 15 = 5
Number generated: 2248
This is _i: 4
Length of list of the key that's being generated (Comparison with what it should): 10 = 5
Generated key = {' ': [955, 2811, 442, 705, 2248, 1091, 350, 1830, 1042, 1814], 'H': [281, 1542, 2710, 516, 34], 'o': [2497, 1384, 88, 1332, 1758, 1861, 1325, 1242, 1885, 1728, 339, 2367, 720, 2532, 1011], 'h': [695, 1207, 2011, 1369, 1593, 377, 2176, 775, 1168, 2641]}
```

As you can see 'h', 'o', and ' ' got 10 to 15 numbers on their lists, which is 2x to 3x the number of numbers than they should, but _i(Shoot I forgot to change that! _i stands for the variable NumberOfTimesRanThroughTheMainLoop, sorry about that!), the index of the insert function, didn't go above 4 as shown, so why did they get numbers on index 9 and 14 and how would I be able to fix it?

Thanks in advance

Note: I edited the full post to make it more readable

Comment: just as an aside, *learn to pick more descriptive names than `i` and various variations on it*

Comment: Sorry about that...

Comment: Can we have complete code ??

Comment: Aside from the "import random" part I think its enough but ok. Just keep in mind its far from finished and it's supposed to be an encripter.

Comment: And it has a LOT of syntax mistakes

Comment: Please read [how to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and follow the advice there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is working as it should.

The reason you have 10 characters for 'h' is because you have two 'h' characters. Because they have the same key, the numbers are appended to the same list. The same happens for 'o' and ' '.

Here is an example of how the loop is working for one iteration, given the string ' Hohoho ' (I'm adding some random numbers) :

```
' ' -> [354]
'H' -> [234]
'o' -> [453]
'h' -> [342]
'o' (again) -> [453, 123] # now it has two elements when it should have 1
'h' -> [342, 633] # 2 elements as well now
'o' -> [453, 123, 1423] # now it has 3 elements
' ' -> [354, 562] # this has 3 elements now
```

As you can see the additional numbers to be expected are the number of letters multiplied by the number of times the loop runs.

If you want to only create numbers for unique characters, you can first make sure the `content` variable is unique (i.e only use unique letters). Replace the content variable before looping:

```
content = ''.join(dict.fromkeys(content))
# content is now ' Hoh' which will give correct results
```

If you don't care about the order of the letters you can also simplify this:

```
content = list(set(content))
```

Comment: I don't quite get it. Aren't the keys and the indexes already unique? And how would I use that? Could you exemplify?

Comment: And I chose the index, why does it append instead of rewriting?

Comment: @abcdeef I updated the answer with explanation. The `insert` method in python actually is similar to append (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) in that it doesn't override the value. If you want to overwrite it you simply write `my_list[index] = new_value`. Of course you have to make sure that the index exists.

Comment: That's pretty stupid... The whole reason why I was using it was because the index didn't exist. I'll see if it works by using the second option, as content is a variable and I don't need to change it. I could do content2 = list(set(content)) and get the exact same dictionary and still have content intact. Thanks a lot